# CSS or JQuery to vertically align text with element floating next to it

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a div floating left that contains text of a larger size than the content to it's right, but I would like the text in the right to be aligned at the bottom of the text in the floating div.  Here's a JS Fiddle showing an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/cykz8vd0/3/

As you can see, the text in the right is misaligned to the letter on the left. I would like it so that the bottom of the first line of the text on the right is aligned with the bottom of the letter on the left.

HTML

```
<div class="floatLeft">
    A:
</div>
<div class="fill">
    Text goes here. I would like it to be aligned nicely with the letter on the left.
    <br>
    Another line of text here.
</div>
```

CSS

```
.floatLeft{
    float:left;
    width:20px;
    font-size:18px;
    font-weight:bold;
}

.fill{
   margin-left:25px;
}
```

The only way I've been able to accomplish this so far is by doing what you see in this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/cykz8vd0/4/

I just changed the `.fill` css to:

```
.fill{
   margin-left:25px;
   position:relative;
   top:3px;
}
```

That `top:3px` will not always work though, because this code will be implemented on pages with different fonts.  Is there any way for me to programmatically calculate what this `top` value should be, so I can set it with JQuery, or is there perhaps a better way to achieve this alignment all together?

Comment: they are misaligned just because they have different font sizes. There's nothing to do to align them properly IMO.

Comment: Vertically aligned to the left or to the right?

Comment: does the `A:` have to be float?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution:

HTML:

```
<div class="fill">
    <div class="floatLeft">A:</div>Text goes here. I would like it to be aligned nicely with the letter on the left.
    <br>
    Another line of text here.
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.floatLeft{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    margin-left: -25px;
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.fill{
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-left:25px;
}
```

Your label is now perfectly aligned to text baseline no matter what `font-size` is. JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cykz8vd0/6/

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for. Are there any downsides to using this method? It seems too good to be true!

Comment: I think I was mistaken as to the OP's request.

Comment: @flyingL123, You're welcome) The only one downside is that there shouldn't be any whitespaces between `<div class="floatLeft">A:</div>` and the following text.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by that? Are you saying there should not be a line break after the closing `.floatLeft` `</div>` tag? I currently am doing it with a line break and it seems to be working correctly.

Comment: @flyingL123, If you add a line break, your text will be slightly indented to the right. See: http://jsfiddle.net/cykz8vd0/11/

Answer (score 2):

There are a few solutions.  One would be to add a `line-height` on your `.fill`s.  This, however, may not be desirable.

Another, assuming you do know the `font-size` of the `.floatLeft` div, would be to use a `::before` pseudo-element like so:

```
.fill::before {
    content: "";
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

This is assuming that the `font-size` of `.floatLeft` is `18px`.  Here's a [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bowheart/cykz8vd0/5/) demonstrating this second method.

Or, if you want to use jQuery, you can do something like this:

```
var height = $('.fill').prev().css('font-size');
var attrs = {"font-size": height, "display": "inline-block", "text-indent": -9999};
$('.fill').prepend('<span>|</span>').find('span').first().css(attrs);
```

Prepend an invisible span to `.fill` and dynamically modify its CSS.

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bowheart/cykz8vd0/10/) using that method.

Answer (score -1):

This will align all of your `.fill`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".fill").each(function () {
        $this = $(this);
        var $floatLeft = $this.prev(".floatLeft");
        var left = $floatLeft.offset().left + $floatLeft.width();
        var top = $floatLeft.offset().top + parseInt($floatLeft.css("font-size")) - parseInt($this.css("font-size"));

        $this.offset({
            left: left,
            top: top
        });
    });
});
```

DEMO: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cykz8vd0/9/)

Comment: Are you sure that JS is necessary in this case?

Comment: @seva.rubbo As question states we don't know the font size I think we need to use JS.